# Refresh a shoutbox

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I've recently started to develop a website for some people, and I cannot seem to get it working properly. My problem is that I don't know how to refresh my shoutbox div. I would be really happy if you could help me out.

```
    <div id="chatbox"> 
        <div class="chatboxi">
    <?php
        $connection = mysql_connect('LocalDB', 'DB', 'Pass');
        mysql_select_db('DBO');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15) sub ORDER BY id Desc"; // Sorts them and takes the 10 first by ID.

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>:" . $row['post'] . "</td></tr>";   //$row['index'] the index here is a field name


        }

        ?>

        </div>
    </div>

</form> 

<form method="POST" name="chatbarf">
    <textarea cols="2" rows="3" id="chatbar" name="chatbar">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="Send" name="Send" onsubmit="">
</form>
```

I've been trying to use this code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#chatbox').fadeOut('slow').load('chat.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 20000);
</script>
```

It didn't work very well. It refreshed the entire page and made double of everything.

Comment: Search about javascript ajax polling if its a periodic update, or websocket if its real time.

Comment: I agree with VMcreator. You will find many Ajax samples online and the easiest choice, websockets are a little more complicated. Ajax will get/post behind the scenes without redirecting or reloading the page, websockets are used to open a connection and listen for changes.

Comment: I just can't seem to get them working properly. That's why i'm asking in here.

Comment: @Jacob Can you define **them**  *"I just can't seem to get `them` working properly".* If you have tried using ajax or websockets, edit your question and display your attempt(s). This will give us something to debug, I'm sure someone will find the error and explain why it isn't working as intended and offer a solution. Without seeing your attempt(s) it's impossible to see or explain where you're going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Jacob I would also like to make another recommendation. Change your php database query. `mysql` to `mysqli` Please check this guide out to see the reason for this recommendation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @NewToJS I've sorted all of my shouts in the shoutboxes by ID. So "them" is my shouts. Also i will make a edit with the stuff i've been trying.

Comment: Shouldn't your interval and jQuery be placed `$(function() {//Here});` so it will only execute when the DOM is ready? Also if you have that execute when the DOM is ready you shouldn't need the block of PHP as the shoutbox will be created when the jQuery is executed. It will mean you might have to move a few things as it will wait for the interval time to hit **0** before the shoutbox loads. Also if chat.php has anything other that the PHP it will also include all other elements on that page. I would recommend having the shoutbox query on it's own php file if it isn't already.

Comment: @NewToJS to be honest i didn't really get much of what you were saying. I got that you would recommend me to make a seperate php. Could you be a bit more detailed? Or even make the code for me.

Comment: @Jacob I have submitted my answer, I hope it helps you and as posted in the answer, if you don't understand anything in the source code please leave a comment below the answer and I will explain the best I can. I would rather you understand the source code and not just use it because it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point for you.

> **SQL to SQLI & jQuery DOM Ready:**
>
> I have updated the php from SQL to SQLI as I recommended but I still recommend you to research SQLI as it's very important to understand the source code you run on your server.

I have also created a function called `GetShouts`. The reason for this is so that if you decide to change your posting method (adding new shouts) to an AJAX method you can call `GetShouts()` and it will update the shoutbox as the user adds a new shout, this will confirm to the user the shout has been added.

**HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Shoutbox</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { //DOM is ready
function GetShouts(){
$('#chatbox').fadeOut('slow').load('chat.php').fadeIn("slow");
}
//Set interval
var auto_refresh = setInterval(GetShouts, 20000);
//Get shouts
GetShouts();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chatbox"></div>
</body></html>
```

**PHP File (chat.php):**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("LocalDB", "DB", "Pass", "DBO");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
die("Connection Failed");
exit();
}
$Output="<table>";
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM shoutbox LIMIT 15")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Output.='<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td><td>'.$row["post"].'</td></tr>';
    }
$result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();
$Output.="</table>";
echo $Output;
?>
```

If you don't understand any of the above source code, please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible adding any necessary comments into the source code.

*Appreciation is show by marking the answer.*

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: @Jacob Happy to help! If you have any problems just leave a comment.